# Vagrantfile and external config - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

Never used Ruby but this seems straight forward enough having looked at a few examples - not working - what am I missing?

**vmconfig.yml:**

```
server:   
    hostname: mydomain.com
```

**Vagrantfile**:

```
require 'yaml'
vmconfig = YAML.load_file('vmconfig.yml')

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/contrib-jessie64"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update

    hostname vmconfig["server"]["hostname"]
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
end
```

hostname is not set (to what config file should) when VM is finished building??? If I hardcode the value it works fine???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use vagrant to define the hostname of the VM like below

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
  SHELL

  config.vm.hostname = vmconfig["server"]["hostname"]
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "virtualbox"
```

You can see [other available settings](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html) that you can define in your Vagrantfile

If you want to run through the yaml and write from script, you need to do it with [string interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    hostname #{vmconfig["server"]["hostname"]}
    .... set other things from yaml with #{<variable>} ....
  SHELL
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated response but I am very curious as to why none of the examples I looked at seemed to use interpolated strings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26394449/897075) this is exactly what I am trying to do. I have to admit, the string interpolation looks awful but it did seem to do the trick - but now I am trying to understand why? What is different between all these examples and what I have?

Comment: I think I may have just figured out why...the examples I looked at are using config.vm.XXX - my bad :)

Comment: no it is not the same - see my first code snippet does not use string interpolation, vagrant will get the expected hostname directly by reading the yaml file; in the 2nd part though I need string interpolation as the whole script is run within a text (the SHELL string variable in this case) so you need a way to tell vagrant the hostname part is has to be read from yaml and its a variable not just some random text

Comment: Right right - gotcha...thank you very much!!! Have yourself a great day :)