# convert space separated string in bash to list in ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, vagrantfile

I have a space separated string of IPs that I am exporting to a Vagrantfile which I want to iterate over.

```
export IP="10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11"
```

I want to perform an operation on this so it becomes a list in the vagrantfile to iterate over.

```
["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: try `ENV['IP'].split(' ')`

Comment: Thanks fangxing, but it seems that I ran into an error when I tried it out


     ENV['IP'].split(' ')
     -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `' ''`


Also tried using the same in the vagrantfile
      Message: NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Am I using it incorrectly? Entirely new to ruby

Answer (score 2):

Try figure it out yourself in bash:

```
$ export IP="10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11"
$ irb  # interactive ruby
> puts ENV['IP']  # make sure IP is not nil
10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11 # output
> IPs = ENV['IP'].split 
> puts IPs
```

`Vagrantfile` is a Ruby script, so you can use `ENV['IP'].split` in it

Comment: Your escaping is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The following should be robust. You would not need to worry about padding by space characters at the beginning or the end of the string, or about irregular sequences of space characters.

```
"10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11".scan(/\S+/)
# => ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa and @fangxing. Both the solutions worked for me if I directly used the IPs in the vagrantfile

`CFG_IP = "10.10.10.11 10.10.10.10".scan(/\S+/)`

The above worked perfectly for me and spun 2 VMs for me with no errors.
How do I substitute the exported variable in the vagrant file?

I tried the following:
`CFG_IP = ENV['LIST_OF_IP'].scan(/\S+/)` This threw an error saying

`Message: NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' `

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Split directly as from the examples,

```
" now's  the time".split        
=> ["now's", "the", "time"]
>> "10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11".split
=> ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
>> "10.10.10.10   10.10.10.11".split
=> ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
>> "   10.10.10.10   10.10.10.11".split
=> ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
>> "".split
=> []
```

Read the Docs [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)

To include variables in vagrant file, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708917/how-do-i-include-variables-in-my-vagrantfile)

Answer (score 0):

Use split in a simple way

```
"10.10.10.10 10.10.10.11".split(' ')
=> ["10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11"]
```